# Microsoft word is showing strange squares

Tags: windows, ms-word, ms-office

I was trying to do something in Microsoft Word and I did something that I can turn back to normal and it's driving me crazy for days already.

So here it is. There are some strange squares that show every new line, doesn't matter if they are blank or not. It looks like this:
[Click here to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ol7M6.png)

EDIT:
The OS is Windows 10 if it is of importance.

How to remove them? Please HELP!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File -> Options -> Advanced (tab) -> "Show document content" section -> uncheck "Show text boundaries". As an advice I would suggest do not do "something" you are not sure about ;)

Comment: LOL. If we never did anything we weren't sure about in Word, we would never learn how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

For MacOS users with the same issue, go to Word menu, Preferences, then View. Uncheck the 'Text boundaries' box.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).